Lifted ttk.Label widget can't redraw promptly?
Here is my minimum representative example (MRE) on how I create ttk.Button widgets with an image via a multithreaded approach. However, I am experiencing an issue with a task that occurs before the multithreading task. Whenever the self.label widget is lifted, it can't be redrawn promptly; a grey patch appears for a short period before self.label appears completely. Running self.update_idletasks()  (see line 97) can't fix this issue. Only running self.update() can fix this issue (you have to uncomment line 98). However, some opined that the use of self.update() can be harmful. Is it possible to resolve this issue without using self.update()? If so, how? Please can you also explain why this issue happens? Thank you.
Issue demo:

Desired outcome demo:

MRE:
Please save any .jpg file you have into the same directory/folder as this script and rename it to testimage.jpg. How this GUI works? Click the Run button to start the multithreading. To rerun, you have to first click Reset button, thereafter click the Run button. DO NOT click Reset when threading is ongoing and vice versa.
# Python modules
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import concurrent.futures as cf
import queue
import threading
from itertools import repeat
import random
from time import sleep

# External modules
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def get_thumbnail_c(gid: str, fid: str, fpath: str, psize=(100, 100)):
    # print(f"{threading.main_thread()=} {threading.current_thread()=}")
    with Image.open(fpath) as img:
        img.load()
    img.thumbnail(psize)
    return gid, fid, img


def get_thumbnails_concurrently_with_queue(
        g_ids: list, f_ids: list, f_paths: list, rqueue: queue.Queue,
        size: tuple):
    futures = []
    job_fn = get_thumbnail_c

    with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor() as vp_executor:
        for gid, fids, fpath in zip(g_ids, f_ids, f_paths):
            for gg, ff, pp in zip(repeat(gid, len(fids)), fids,
                                  repeat(fpath, len(fids))):
                job_args = gg, ff, pp, size
                futures.append(vp_executor.submit(job_fn, *job_args))
    for future in cf.as_completed(futures):
        rqueue.put(("thumbnail", future.result()))
        futures.remove(future)
        if not futures:
            print(f'get_thumbnails_concurrently has completed!')
            rqueue.put(("completed", ()))


class GroupNoImage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, gid, fids):
        super().__init__(master, style='gframe.TFrame')
        self.bns = {}
        self.imgs = {}
        for i, fid in enumerate(fids):
            self.bns[fid] = ttk.Button(self, text=f"{gid}-P{i}", compound="top",
                                       style="imgbns.TButton")
            self.bns[fid].grid(row=0, column=i, stick="nsew")

class App(ttk.PanedWindow):
    def __init__(self, master, **options):
        super().__init__(master, **options)
        self.master = master
        self.groups = {}
        self.rqueue = queue.Queue()

        self.vsf = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.add(self.vsf)

        self.label = ttk.Label(
            self, style="label.TLabel", width=7, anchor="c", text="ttk.Label",
            font=('Times', '70', ''))
        self.label.place(
            relx=0.5, rely=0.5, relwidth=.8, relheight=.8, anchor="center",
            in_=self.vsf)
        self.label.lower(self.vsf)

    def create_grpsframe(self):
        self.grpsframe = ttk.Frame(self.vsf, style='grpsframe.TFrame')
        self.grpsframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    def run(self, event):
        self.create_grpsframe()
        gids = [f"G{i}" for i in range(50)]
        random.seed()
        fids = []
        for gid in gids:
            f_ids = []
            total = random.randint(2,10)
            for i in range(total):
                f_ids.append(f"{gid}-P{i}" )
            fids.append(f_ids)
        fpaths = ["testimage.jpg" for i in range(len(gids))]
        self.create_groups_concurrently(gids, fids, fpaths)

    def reset(self, event):
        self.grpsframe.destroy()
        self.groups.clear()

    def create_groups_concurrently(self, gids, fids, fpaths):
        print(f"\ncreate_groups_concurrently")

        self.label.lift(self.vsf)
        # self.update_idletasks()  # Can't fix self.label appearance issue
        # self.update()  # Fixed self.label appearance issue

        for i, (gid, f_ids) in enumerate(zip(gids, fids)):
            self.groups[gid] = GroupNoImage(self.grpsframe, gid, f_ids)
            self.groups[gid].grid(row=i, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.update_idletasks()
        # sleep(3)
        print(f"\nStart thread-queue")

        jthread = threading.Thread(
            target=get_thumbnails_concurrently_with_queue,
            args=(gids, fids, fpaths, self.rqueue, (100,100)),
            name="jobthread")
        jthread.start()
        self.check_rqueue()

    def check_rqueue(self):
        # print(f"\ndef _check_thread(self, thread, start0):")
        duration = 1  # millisecond
        try:
            info = self.rqueue.get(block=False)
            # print(f"{info=}")
        except queue.Empty:
            self.after(1, lambda: self.check_rqueue())
        else:
            match info[0]:
                case "thumbnail":
                    gid, fid, img = info[1]
                    print(f"{gid=} {fid=}")
                    grps = self.groups
                    grps[gid].imgs[fid] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
                    grps[gid].bns[fid]["image"] = grps[gid].imgs[fid]
                    self.update_idletasks()
                    self.after(duration, lambda: self.check_rqueue())
                case "completed":
                    print(f'Completed')
                    self.label.lower(self.vsf)

class ButtonGroups(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **options):
        super().__init__(master, style='bnframe.TFrame', **options)
        self.master = master
        self.bnrun = ttk.Button(
            self, text="Run", width=10, style='bnrun.TButton')
        self.bnreset = ttk.Button(
            self, text="Reset", width=10, style='bnreset.TButton')

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.bnrun.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.bnreset.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('1300x600')
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    ss = ttk.Style()
    ss.theme_use('default')
    ss.configure(".", background="gold")
    ss.configure("TPanedwindow", background="red")
    ss.configure('grpsframe.TFrame', background='green')
    ss.configure('gframe.TFrame', background='yellow')
    ss.configure('imgbns.TButton', background='orange')
    ss.configure("label.TLabel", background="cyan")
    ss.configure('bnframe.TFrame', background='white')
    ss.configure('bnrun.TButton', background='violet')
    ss.configure('bnreset.TButton', background='green')

    app = App(root)
    bns = ButtonGroups(root)
    app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    bns.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    bns.bnrun.bind("<B1-ButtonRelease>", app.run)
    bns.bnreset.bind("<B1-ButtonRelease>", app.reset)

    root.mainloop()


There is way more code than I'm willing to examine. However, try using the state option with hidden and normal if that's an option for you.

You keep telling tkinter to call check_rqueue 1000 times a second until all of the images are shown. It is possible that it can't find enough time to properly draw the ttk.Label. Try increasing the delay in both .after() calls to 20. Also if you have no bindings that can be activated while the .update() is running, it should be safe.

@TheLizzard it shouldn't be much of a difference from 1 to 20, since the mainloop itself just cycle in about 20ms intervals. Only 0 or an higher interval would make a difference.

@Thingamabobs I managed to remove the use of the external module scrframe.py to shorten my MRE. Issue persists. So the above script is all there is to examine.

this grey patch is your self.label before tkiner has time to fill it with all elements. Python is not so fast, and tkinter is not so fast (it runs code in language tcl), and you have many thumbnail to display (I don't means convert but only display it in window) - so tkinter may not have time to draw label in short time. Did you tried to run it for less images? If you don't find method to optimize it then you may need to use other GUI framework. ie. PyQt

@furas I notice that the grey patch of self.label always occur when lifted from a lowered position. I found this out by commenting out the first lowing instruction at line 69. The appearance ofself.labelis correct when created. Don't understand whyself.update_idletasks` can't solve it since it is a redrawing issue. Reducing it to 5 rows also can't solve this issue.

I might find some time on the weekend. But some things I would try for a quick fix self.after(0, self.label.lift). If that doesn't work out why not makes this label a model window, an actual window, to get it out of the redrawing cycle? Also comment out all print statements while testing.

In addition.. why not lift the label and call your heavy computation with after to ensure the label is drawn correctly?

@Thingamabobs self.label is meant to obscure self.vsf when it's appearance is in transition.  self.after(0, self.label.lift) did not work. If the label is part of another toplevel window, can it be lifted just before and at the end of the thread? My goal is to use get_thumbnails_concurrently_with_queue() to do the heavy computes and I can't do it with or link it with the after method.

Thank you @Thingamabobs. Your comment worked:

why not lift the label and call your heavy computation with after to
ensure the label is drawn correctly?

My amendment is given below. Extra calls to the self.update_idletasks() and self.update() methods were not even needed. In so doing, tkinter's main event loop was also promptly serviced. Although I obtained the desired outcome by using the .after_idle() method for this MRE, I noticed that the .after() method gave a more robust outcome in my actual code.
Amendments:
def run(self, event):
    self.create_grpsframe()
    gids = [f"G{i}" for i in range(50)]
    random.seed()
    fids = []
    for gid in gids:
        f_ids = []
        total = random.randint(2,10)
        for i in range(total):
            f_ids.append(f"{gid}-P{i}" )
        fids.append(f_ids)
    fpaths = ["testimage.jpg" for i in range(len(gids))]
    self.label.lift(self.vsf)  # Put this statement here instead of in the self.create_groups_concurrently method.
    self.after_idle(self.create_groups_concurrently, gids, fids, fpaths)  # Then use the after_idle() method to call the method that start the threads.


Happy to see it worked out for you.

@Thingamabobs My issue seems to be caused by line 103. Without implementing your comment and simply not do the self.update_idletasks() in a for-loop, this issue goes away. Do you know why this is the case? Also, the other self.update_idletasks command at line 130 seems to be redundant. In short, it seems that a generous use of  the .update_idletasks() method can be problematic too. Can you advice on what are the good common practices for using and not using the update_idletasks() method?

Imagine these commands as screaming at your employees. The update_idletasks is just screaming NOW! while update is more like WORK! WORK! WORK!. Putting your employees under pressure with update leads to careless errors, while giving the command NOW! can work for both sides. However, most of the time, even the command NOW! is a sign of poor management and you should reconsider if there isn't a better way to solve this situation.

To be less abstract, I use update_idletasks sometimes when I initiating a new window, after every instruction put in the queue and the window is ready/mapped I flush the idle tasks.

Another use of update_idletasks would be, you size a container and need real values, you flush the tasks to have them. However, winfo_reqwidth() is most of the time accurate.

For Tk to function correctly, you have to service its event loop, and to do so pretty much continuously. This is when little things like the instructions from the OS to say when and where a window is to be really drawn are received.
You should call the tk.mainloop() function.

Recommended Reading:

Tkinter understanding mainloop


OP has already executed root.mainloop() in the code.

Your recommended reading reinforced my understanding on the update and update_idletasks methods. Thanks. Yes, The mainloop method is used.
